# GPGS Unity Plugin - Network Latency Check & Synchronisation

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, real-time

I'm trying to develop a realtime multiplayer game in Unity using Google Play Games plugin. So far, it all has been pretty straightforward. I'm using a P2P architecture.

One of the issues I have is that the data I'm sending to players is time sensitive. I can use and send an unreliable message, but we know that no two players will have the same set of data or 'game state' at any given point. Is there any way I can synchronise my players? my understanding is that having even a client-server architecture will only help me synchronise players to a certain degree, but not completely. Is that correct?

My knowledge of networking, especially with Google Play, is very limited so if you can explain this to me like I'm five, that'd be great. ^_^

Comment: what about sending on your messages the "timestamp"? so every player will know WHEN this package have been sended, and operate like that

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.